# Integer solutions to $ab=a+b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $ab=a+b$ is there only one possible solution,i.e. $a=b=2$? ($a$ and $b$ not equal to zero and are integers).
If not what are the others?

I have proved that $a$ always needs to be equal to $b$. My proof is as follows- $ab=\cdot a\cdot a\cdot \cdots$ ($b$ times). Since the product is a factor of $a$ then clearly $b$ must be equal to $a$ for the equation to hold true. Please help me with all the possible solutions and is $2$ is the only possible solution please help me to prove it that it is the only possible solution. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: $a,b$ are integers?

Comment: What about $a=b=0$?

Comment: also shouldn't that be $ab=a+a+a+\cdots+a$ ($b$ times)?

Comment: @mathlove-Yes they are.

Comment: @MattB-No they are integers not equal to 0.

Answer (score 15):

If $ab=a+b$, then $ab-a-b+1=1$, or $(a-1)(b-1)=1$. Then if $a$ and $b$ are integers, we have either $a-1=b-1=1$, and $a=b=2$, or $a-1=b-1=-1$ and $a=b=0$. If $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily integers, then choose a nonzero real number $r$, then $a=r+1$, $b=\frac{1}{r}+1$ is a solution to the equation.

Comment: How did you find out a=r+1 and b=1/r+1 will be a solution to this equation.Is there any method?

Comment: @tatan Just let $r=a-1$, then you have $r(b-1)=1$, so solve for $b$ and $a$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to rely on jgon's clever trick of adding $1$ to both sides of an equation. $ab=a+b \Leftrightarrow ab-b=(a-1)b=a$. This means that $(a-1)$ is a factor of $a$. In the integers, that can only be true in two cases: $(a-1)=1$ or $a=0$. Simple substitution and arithmetic using those values gives the previously identified solutions, $a=b=2$ and $a=b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can have $ab=a+b$ so $ab-a-b=0$ so $a(b-1)-b=0$ so $a(b-1)-(b-1)=1$ so $(a-1)(b-1)=1$. $(a,b)=(2,2)$ is one integer solution. There is also $-1
\cdot-1)$ so $(0,0)$ is the other integer solution. However, there are infinite non-integer solutions. We know that $\frac{1}{2}\cdot2=1$, $\frac{1}{3}\cdot3=1$, etc etc. So there are infinite solutions, like $(2,2) (\frac{3}{2},3), (\frac{4}{3},4)$ and so on. This is a bit like a previous post, but the reason that there are infinite is because if $a-1$ is some number greater than 0, call it $x$, then $\frac{1}{x+1}$ and $x-1\cdot \frac{1}{x+1}$ is the value of $b$ so that $ab=1$. Because there are infinite number that are $\neq0$, there are $\inf$ values of $a$ and $b$ that work, but $2$ integer values that work. This is quite similar to other posts, just sharing the way I did it.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, this is an answer to an old question that already has an answer just like yours. If you want to help here, please work on new questions that don't yet have answers.