# Solve $x + y + z = xyz$ such that $x , y , z \neq0$

Tags: arithmetic

I came across the equation $x+y+z=xyz$ such that $x , y , z \neq 0$.

I set $x=1, y=2, z=3$ but how can i reach formal mathematical solution without " guessing " the answer ? Thank you

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613105/all-solutions-of-abc-abc-in-natural-numbers

Comment: you can solve the equation for $z$, say, which gives $z=\frac{x+y}{xy-1}$ for $xy\neq1$. If $xy=1$, then the equation is equivalent to $x=-y$ and then $1=xy=-y^2$, which is not possible. Hence we are allowed to explude this case, and all solutions are given by $(x,y,z)$, where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary (and not zero) and $z=\frac{x+y}{xy-1}$ with $xy\neq1$.
EDIT: I saw the first comment. Do you want to have $x,y,z$ be NATURAL numbers?

Comment: Also related with $n=1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378804/numbers-of-the-form-fracxyzxyz-second-question

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for positive $$x,y,z$$ then the following image provides a nice geometrical interpretation of your problem: 
[image: A triangle with a inscribed unit circle.]

**Proof**
Consider the complex product $$(1+ix)(1+iy)(1+iz)$$ of which the imaginary part is zero, since the sum of the arguments of the complex factors equals: $$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi$$
However, since $$\Im((1+ix)(1+iy)(1+iz)) = (x+y+z) - xyz$$ we have:  $$x+y+z = xyz $$    ∎

Answer (score 3):

The condition
$$x+y+z=xyz\ne0\tag{1}$$
defines a certain set $S$ in $(x,y,z)$-space. This set is only *implicitly* described by $(1)$, which means that $(1)$ provides a quick test whether any given point $P=(x,y,z)$ belongs to $S$ or not.

What you want is an *explicit* description of $S$ in the form of a list of points (if $S$ were finite), or a parametric representation with free variables. Since $(1)$ can be algebraically solved for $z$ in the form
$$z={x+y\over xy-1}$$
we see that above each point $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ lies at most one point of $S$. Therefore we immediately arrive at the parametric representation
$$S:\quad (x,y)\mapsto\left(x,y,{x+y\over xy-1}\right)\ .$$
So far this is just formal, and we have to exclude certain parameter points $(x,y)$. These are the points $(x,y)$ on the hyperbola $xy=1$, the points on the $x$- and the $y$ axis, and the points on the line $x+y=0$. All in all we come to the conclusion that $S$ is a union of $8$ disjoint surfaces, each of these lying over some part of the $(x,y)$-plane.

Answer (score 3):

For:$$A,B,C\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}),and \,A+B+C=\pi$$

then:$$\tan{A}+\tan{B}+\tan{C}=\tan{A}\tan{B}\tan{C}$$

Answer (score 1):

you can write $y+z=x(yz-1)$ and if $yz\ne1$ you will get $$x=\frac{y+z}{yz-1}$$
if $yz=1$ we get $y+z=0$ or $y^2+1=0$ which gives us complex solutions.

Comment: Ok thanks but in a sense it indeed simplifies and helps but still requires me to put numbers - that is a guess of the solution , My question is how or is it possible to get an accurate answer without having to guess and answers do not have to be Natural numbers, thanks

Comment: @sharon The parametric solutions are perfect, you have two parameters (in them) and put "any" numbers (with conditions) in the parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Solve for one variable. As the problem is symmetric, wlog solve for $z$:
$$z = \frac{x+y}{xy-1}.$$
Now you can choose any real values for $x$ and $y$, as long as $xy-1\ne0$. For your choice of $x=1$, $y=2$, you can see it gives the correct result.

If you need a solution in $\mathbb Z$, things get more complicated as the value of $z$ could be a rational for most choices of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $x = 1$, then $yz = y+z$.

Let $y = z$, then $y\cdot y = y^2 = 2y$.

$\frac{y^2}y = y = 2$.

Using substitution of $x=1$, $y=2$:

$1 + 2 + z = 2z$

$1 + 2 = 2z-z$

$z=3$

$1\times2\times3 = 1 + 2 + 3$

If $x = y = z$, $x$ to $z$ would equal $3^{\frac12}$ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).