# If $x+y+z=xyz$ then is it true that at most one of the numbers can be negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, 3d

> If $x+y+z=xyz$ then is it true that at most one of the numbers can be negative?

My book says this statement is false but I am not able to think of any counter example.

[toppr website](https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-af/question/statement-1if-displaystyle-xyz-xyz-then-at-most-one-of-the-numbers-can-be-negative/) says this statement is true.

I have found two links on MSE. I am not able to conclude from that either. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613105/all-solutions-of-abc-abc-in-natural-numbers) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240229/solve-x-y-z-xyz-such-that-x-y-z-neq0).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139595/discussion-on-question-by-aarbee-if-xyzxyz-then-is-it-true-that-at-most-one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Anne Bauval's comment.

$$x+y=z(xy-1)\\\implies z=\frac{x+y}{xy-1}$$

Since, $xy\ne1$,

let $x=-2,y=-1$, thus $z=\frac{-2-1}{2-1}=-3$.

It implies the given claim is incorrect. **All the three numbers can be negative simultaneously.**

Another example, $x=-\frac12, y=-\frac13$, thus, $z=\frac{-\frac12-\frac13}{\frac16-1}=1$.

It shows **exactly two numbers can be negative too.**

Comment: Dividing by $xy - 1$ doesn't prove that $xy \ne 1$, it assumes it.  So "Since $xy \ne 1$" rather than "thus", or even "when $xy \ne 1$".

Comment: @DanielV thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative derivation of counter-example.

Sufficient that two of the three numbers are negative.

Let $x,y,z$ be represented by $1+r,1,1+s,$ respectively.

Then, $r,s$ must be derived to satisfy

$$1 + r + s + rs = 3 + r + s ~: ~r,s < -1 \implies $$

$$rs = 2.$$

This has the easy solution of

$r = s = -\sqrt{2}.$

Then

$$\left(1 - \sqrt{2}\right) \times 1 \times \left(1 - \sqrt{2}\right) = \left(3 - 2\sqrt{2}\right) $$

$$= \left(1 - \sqrt{2}\right) + 1 + \left(1 - \sqrt{2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume there exists a solution to $x+y+z=xyz$ having one negative number, WLOG let the negative term be $z$, with $x,y$ being positive. Then we know that $xyz$ is a negative number $=-|x||y||z|$

Now multiply each term by $-1$. Now the sum has two negative terms and one positive term, and is equal to the negative of the sum in the first case. Plainly the product is now a positive number $=|x||y||z|$ and the sum is simply the negative of the sum in the first instance, which is $=-(-|x||y||z|)=|x||y||z|$

So a solution with one negative term implies the existence of a solution with two negative terms.

I note by the same argument, if there is a solution with $3$ positive terms. then multiplying by $-1$ affords a solution with $3$ negative terms.